# Elegant way of getting indexes of an array

Tags: c#, linq, for-loop

I'm having hard time with switching to LINQ with the following example:

```
int[] inputs = { 5, 3, 5, 66, 4, 5 };
int[] indexes; // I want to have the indexes of '5's in 
               // the inputs array, which is { 0, 2, 5 }

// My way (traditional for loop)

List<int> indexesList = new List<int>();
for (int i = 0; i < inputs.Length; i++)
    if (inputs[i] == 5)
        indexesList.Add(i);

indexes = indexesList.ToArray();

// LINQ way

var indexes = inputs.Select((s, i) => new { i, s })
                    .Where(t => t.s == 5)
                    .Select(t => t.i).ToArray();
```

**Question 1.** In terms of **efficiency** (speed, memory usage), am I going to have any advantage if I convert my code to LINQ?

**Question 2.** If true, is there a more **elegant way** of doing it with LINQ?

PS: Note that, this method is called very frequently in my real project. So, having a little improvement in speed or memory usage will help the overall process a lot.

Comment: How many elements are in `inputs` on average. Optimization depends on very specific cases.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: @igrimpe, `inputs` is an array which has `784` elements. However, I call this method more than `10k` times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are certainly *not* going to have a *performance* advantage if your use the LINQ code. This is evident simply by reading it: to associate each value with its index, a new object is created:

```
(s, i) => new { i, s }
```

These anonymous objects serve no other purpose than being a vessel to glue index together with value; therefore all the associated memory management is pure overhead compared to straight up keeping a counter.

One might say that LINQ provides a *readability* advantage because most of the time *it highlights the intent instead of the mechanism*, but in this particular case I don't think it's any better than the prosaic solution.

Comment: Yea, but the LINQ is faulted anyway. If he only needs the indexes, there is no need to create an object/index pair.

Comment: @igrimpe: There's no other way to do that and at the same time filter on values with LINQ. The given solution is as direct as possible, unless you write an iterator block (but then it's not really "stock LINQ" anymore, it's a loop hidden behind a method call and you can do the same without LINQ).

Comment: from i in enumerable.range(0, inputs.length) where inputs(i).s = 5 select i.

Comment: @igrimpe: You cannot really do that if `inputs` is typed as `IEnumerable` instead of being an array.

Comment: OP defined `input` as array.

Comment: igrimpe,  you have a fair point,  post your Linq as an answer.

Comment: @igrimpe: Is your comment faster than the other proposed methods?

Comment: @igrimpe: The OP also hardcoded the values 5, 3, 5, 66, 4, 5 into the array. Are you sure their real code does that as well?

Comment: Jon, whatever it is, it is indexed, because thats what he's after, indexes, so his linq will work.

Comment: I tried all the proposed methods, traditional for loop method is faster than all methods. So, since @Jon told the same, I'm flagging this post as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say that the linq way there is actually less efficient, since you first convert your structure to a collection of tuples, and then select the indices.

Even though it might look more graceful, I'd also say it's a little bit harder to comprehend what exactly is going on there.

I'd personally just recommend the iteration.

If you really need a boost in efficiency, I'd recommend sorting your inputs if at all practical.  The first time you sort them, it will take some time, but it will pay for itself if you search the same list multiple times.

Comment: The input array is a generic array which comes perfectly different at every time. So, sorting is probably will not make any help in this case.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it the LINQ way, I would suggest implementing your own extension method for returning the indexes of the elements that match a predicate.

```
public static IEnumerable<int> IndexesWhere<TSource>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> source, 
    Func<TSource, bool> predicate)
{
    int i = 0;

    foreach (TSource element in source)
    {
        if (predicate(element))
            yield return i;

        i++;
    }
}
```

You can then call it like so:

```
var indexes = inputs.IndexesWhere(s => s == 5);
```

The advantages of using this approach are:

1. You avoid creating instances of an anonymous type (unlike the `Select((s, i) => new { i, s })` approach).
2. The sequence may be enumerated on demand, meaning it would be more efficient than populating the full array of indexes if you just want to do something like `indexes.Take(2)`.

Comment: Quick question about extension methods : Where do you keep the extension code exactly ? In the same file that make uses of it ? In a common class library ? In a separate file in the same project ?

Comment: Separate file and static class, with the name corresponding to the base class (or interface) I'm extending, plus the word "Extensions". In the above case, I would call it `EnumerableExtensions`.

Comment: What about the performance issue with this answer compared to the traditional loop way?

Comment: That would boil down to the performance of enumerators (such as in `foreach` loops) vs `for` loops. The main advantage of the above approach is that it permits deferred execution (which is a central idea in most of LINQ).

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to use LINQ and avoid creating anonymous objects.

```
var indexes = Enumerable.Range(0, inputs.Length)
                        .Where(x => inputs[x] == 5)
                        .ToArray();
```

Its performance is probably similar to using a for loop, but you will have to test it to be sure.